# Server Socket Programming - Read HTTP header

Tags: sockets, http, parsing, go, get

I am trying to write an HTTP server in Go for school. I am required to AVOID any libraries that make this task easy (the net/http for example).

My problem is that I cannot seem to display the HTTP Response headers correctly. I want to print each header to my terminal, line by line.

I have written this program in Java, and it works well, however, I would like to have this working with a Go program.

I have a function called 'handleClient' that takes an accepted socket.

```
func handleClient(c net.Conn) {
  defer c.Close()
  req, _ := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadString('\n')
  fmt.Print(string(req))
```

When using a web browser to connect to 'localhost:8080', my terminal displays "GET / HTTP/1.1", which is correct, however, I need the additional lines to be posted as well. I understand that 'ReadString('\n') is what is stopping this from happening, however, it is the only way I know of to end that line.

How to I start additional lines?

Comment: You can call [ReadString](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) inside a loop until you hit `EOF`.

Comment: I want to do that, but ReadString seems to require a single bit to use as a delimiter. I am not sure how to proceed with that. I have searched and searched for other methods but have not found any, I am pretty new to GO. I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [ReadString](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) inside a loop until you hit `EOF`.

Something like this:

```
func handleClient(c net.Conn) {
  defer c.Close()
  r := bufio.NewReader(c)
  for {
      req, err := r.ReadString('\n')
      if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
          panic(err)
      }
      fmt.Println(req)

      // break the loop if the err is eof
      if err == io.EOF {
          break
      }
  }
```

Comment: Actually, breaking on EOF does not work, but I am much further. Currently working on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

mkopriva pointed me in the right direction, however, EOF is not the correct way to break the loop. I need to stop looping when I run into a line that is blank. Technically it is never EOF.

To do this, I have adjusted the if condition to break the loop to the following:

```
if len(req) <=2 {
```

After all the headers are read / printed, an HTTP request will end with "\r\n" I believe. I can confirm that the last line is intact of length 2.

Thanks for the help!